# How to render into multiple textures in Vulkan?

Tags: graphics, rendering, vulkan

I want to have an offscreen render pass to render multiple shadow maps for different light sources.

The only ways I can think of are either to have a large number of color attachments or recreate the render pass before render the next shadow map.

I believe there is a more efficient way, like dynamic uniform buffers, that allows me to render into multiple targets with one render pass?

Comment: "*I want to have an offscreen render pass to render multiple shadow maps for different light sources.*" Unless those light sources are in the same *place*, each light source defines a different camera matrix. Which means your VS produces a different set of outputs. Which means you'd be rasterizing different triangles. Which means you're basically issuing a new *drawing command*. So what exactly is the saving here?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas
Hi. I'm doing deferred rendering so I need to save the shadowmaps for the later shading pass.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If you're rendering into a bunch of render targets at *different times*, with different source data (and sometimes with different meshes because some meshes won't be in the view region for those meshes), what's wrong with just using different rendering passes?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas The meshes and model matrices are the same. Only light information (position, color, VP matrix) will change. And I store all light information into one UBO. What I am planing is to iterate each light inside the vertex shader.

Comment: That makes no sense. A VS can only write a single vertex. What you're doing would require turning one *primitive* (composed of multiple vertices) into several primitives, each being rasterized into different layers. A VS can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can create a multilayer framebuffer, then use geometry shader to generate  vertices in different view spaces. use gl_Layer to specify which layer to render.
2. or you can use mulitview feature(need VK_KHR_multiview extension), specify render layer by gl_ViewIndex in vertex shader. This method is said to be faster than previous one.